# Issue with react state not updating/incrementing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to do pagination by clicking on some text that calls a method to increment the state value. The state value then gets passed to the axios call which should then call the next page. I'm noticing however that while the state is getting increment in a console.log from the render function, the axios call is not getting called again with the new state value. Anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        people: [],
        planets: [],
        page: 1
    };
    this.pageIncrementer = this.pageIncrementer.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
    let page = this.state.page;
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `http://localhost:3008/people?_page=${page}&_limit=10`
    }).then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            people: response
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('There is an error in the Card axios call for people: ', error);
    })
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `http://localhost:3008/planets?_page=${page}&_limit=10`
    }).then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            planets: response
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('There is an error in the Card axios call for planets: ', error);
    })
}

pageIncrementer() {
    this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentWillMount` called only once, you need `componentDidUpdate`
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

```
let getData = () => Math.random();

class Example extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
          this.state = {
                name: ''
          };
        }

        componentWillMount(){
             console.log('componentWillMount')
        }

        componentDidUpdate(){
             console.log('componentDidUpdate') 
        }

        handleChange(e) {
          this.setState({
            name: this.props.getData()
          });
        }


        render() {
            return <div className="widget"> 
            {this.state.name}
            <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Inc</button>

            </div>;
        }
      }

      React.render(<Example getData={getData}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Edit(alternative way):

```
let getData = () => Math.random();

class Example extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.makeRequest = this.makeRequest.bind(this)
          this.state = {
                page:1,
                name:''
          };
        }

        makeRequest(next){
             fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+this.state.page)
             .then(
                result => {
                 console.log('do')
                 return result.json()}
             )
             .then(
                 (resp) => this.setState({
                 name:resp, page:this.state.page+1})
             )
        }


        render() {
            return <div className="widget"> 
            {this.state.name}
            <button onClick={this.makeRequest}>Request</button>

            </div>;
        }
      }

      React.render(<Example getData={getData}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Could you give me an example from my code on how I'd use componentDid Update? I'm not too familiar with it and would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm getting the pagination to work but it seems to be in an infinite loop without me even clicking the next page button.

NVM i got it, thanks for your help, i had to add an if conditional to componentdidmount to check states if they changed.